A function is positive on a set with positive Lebesgue outer measure, the integral is also positive?
Let $f\geq 0$ be a measurable function on $[0,1]$, suppose there exists a set $S\subset[0,1]$ with positive Lebesgue outer measure, such that $f>0$ on $S$. Can we deduce that $$\int_{[0,1]}f(x)dx>0?$$
If $S$ is a Lebesgue measurable set, then the conclusion is obvious. Can we have the same conclusion if $S$ is not a Lebesgue measurable set?

When you posit the case where $S$ is not measurable, do you intend that $f = 0$ outside $S$? If so, that would contradict the initial stipulation that $f$ is a measurable function.

Yes we can. Assume $f$ integrates to $0$ on $[0,1]$, then by elementary properties of Lebesgue integrals, $f=0$ almost everywhere. In particular, $f>0$ only on a set of Lebesgue (outer) measure $0$, a contradiction.

I can give another approach. Consider the set $A=\{x|f(x)>0\}$, which is Lebesgue measurable, and $S\subset A$, therefore $m(A)=m^*(A)\geq m^*(S)>0.$
